# Reading text file that has specific format

Tags: java, function, io, text-files

I was looking for some help on how to read a text file that has a specific format, and assign them to variables within my program.

**TextFile.txt**

```
//Variables
start={x}
forward={c}
end={y}
pause={p}
path={x, c, c, c, c, p, c, c, y}
```

**Class.java**

```
public void readFile()
{

char start, forward, end, pause; 

BufferedReader reader = 
    new BufferedReader (
        new InputStreamReader (new FileInputStream (TextFile.txt)));

String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null)
{
    if (line.startWith ("//") || line.trim ().isEmpty ())
        continue; // Ignore the line

    //**This is the part I need help with**
}
}
```

Could somebody please explain how I could assign the values to the variables from the text file?

So for example, start would equal 'x', forward would equal 'c', etc.

Thanks.

Comment: In the above example, is `path` an array?

Comment: path will be a linked-list, with each node being a char.

Comment: Are those the only variables in the file? What about back, left, right etc?

Comment: Yes, the above are the only variables in the file. The file isn't going to be wrote to (only read) so the number of variables wouldn't ever increase or decrease.

Comment: Is it `new FileInputStream(TextFile.txt)` or `new FileInputStream("TextFile.txt")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.startsWith("//") || line.trim().isEmpty())
        continue;
    else if(line.startsWith("start"))
        start= line.charAt(line.indexOf("{")+1);
    else if(line.startsWith("forward"))
        forward= line.charAt(line.indexOf("{")+1);
    else if(line.startsWith("end"))
        end= line.charAt(line.indexOf("{")+1);
    else if(line.startsWith("pause"))
        pause= line.charAt(line.indexOf("{")+1);
    else if(line.startsWith("path"))
        for(String s: line.substring(line.indexOf("{")+1, line.indexOf("}")).split(", "))
                path.add(s.charAt(0));
```

This assumes that your path is defined as `LinkedList<Character> path = new LinkedList<>();`.

Comment: You may replace every `if` after the first if with `else if`

Answer (score 1):

Add this in the class:

```
java.util.Properties p = new java.util.Properties();
```

Add this to your code in the while loop after the if statement:

```
int index = line.indexOf("=");
String var = line.substring(0, index);
int s1 = line.indexOf("{");
int s2 = line.indexOf("}");
String value = line.substring(s1, s2);
p.setProperty(var, value);
```

In the above code, `var` is your variable and `value` is the value of `var`.

You can further process `value` to check if it contains `,` (comma) and if it contains, make a linkedList out of it.